# Connecting to MySQL from Excel VBA

Tags: mysql, excel

I found a few posts to this question but I do not understand one thing:
I do NOT have installed MySQL driver 32 bit for my Excel 2010-32 bit and therefore I cannot use a connection like this:

```
Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver};Provider=MSDASQL;Server=xx.yy.zzz.34;Port=3306;Database=mydatabase;User=myuser;Option=3;
```

BUT: I copied this connection string from another of my Excel-files (32-bit of course) which created the connection string with the "MySQL for Excel" Add-In.

Why does this connection work??

When I do it manually by VBA I get an error that the file

> C:\Programme (x86)\MySQL\Connector ODBC 5.3\myodbc5a.dll cannot be
>   found.

Of course not, because this folder does not exist.
But why can the Add-In use the correct 32-bit driver when I have not installed it on that machine?
Is there only one driver for 32/64 bit??
Very strange!

How can I use a VBA connection to connect to MySQL.

I can protect the macro to hide the password in the connection string. Using the Excel-Add-In I have to give the password to the users.

Thx Michael

Comment: If you don't have the driver installed, then you can't query the database via ODBC. I suspect that the MySQL For Excel add in probably brings in the necessary libraries to do an ODBC connection to excel, doing essentially what you are doing through VBA, but using a wizard/gui.

Comment: As another option, you could create a web api on top of the mysql server that serves up the data via xml, which then could be consumed by excel. That means some development on another language like php or .net or what-have-you, but it will make it so you don't have to drop ODBC drivers on everyone's PC.

Comment: You are right, installing ODBC driver to users PC is not a good solution. As I cannot do it in php (I am not familiar with it) I have to find another solution. As I catch that data from MySQL already through a Linked server within SQL database I think I can schedule a task which runs the stored procedure and then I can manage the data on my machine and deploy the results in any format (Excel, csv, pdf). So the user gets his data through my local application. Thx Michael